# ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS After installing certbot on nginx / Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: web, ssl-certificate, ubuntu-20.04

I have been using apache for a while but I just recently started using nginx. So I still have a lot to learn about it. Here's my problem in detail :

After I've followed [this tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-nginx-on-ubuntu-20-04) I've tried to install an ssl certificate on my server, but it didn't work. So I followed [another tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-secure-nginx-with-let-s-encrypt-on-ubuntu-20-04) to try and install an ssl certificate, it worked at first, but after some time it started doing the problem stated in the title. Here are my .conf files, if you can help me that would be great:

**I've replaced the real domain with my_domain*

This is the /var/www/sites-available/my_domain :

```
server {

        root /var/www/my_domain/html;
        index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

        server_name my_domain;

        location / {
                rewrite ^(/.*)\.html(\?.*)?$ $1$2 permanent;
                rewrite ^/(.*)/$ /$1 permanent;
                try_files $uri/index.html $uri.html $uri/ $uri =404;
        }

    listen [::]:443 ssl ipv6only=on; # managed by Certbot
    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/my_domain/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/my_domain/privkey.pem; # managed by Cert>    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

}
server {
    if ($host = my_domain) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


        listen 80;
        listen [::]:80;

        server_name my_domain;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot

}
```

This is the /var/www/sites-enabled/my_domain :

```
server {

        root /var/www/my_domain/html;
        index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

        server_name my_domain;

        location / {
                rewrite ^(/.*)\.html(\?.*)?$ $1$2 permanent;
                rewrite ^/(.*)/$ /$1 permanent;
                try_files $uri/index.html $uri.html $uri/ $uri =404;
        }

    listen [::]:443 ssl ipv6only=on; # managed by Certbot
    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/my_domain/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/my_domain/privkey.pem; # managed by Cert>    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

}
server {
    if ($host = my_domain) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


        listen 80;
        listen [::]:80;

        server_name my_domain;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot


}
```

My ufw settings :

```
Status: active

To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
22/tcp                     ALLOW       Anywhere                  
22                         ALLOW       Anywhere                  
Nginx Full                 ALLOW       Anywhere                  
22/tcp (v6)                ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)             
22 (v6)                    ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)             
Nginx Full (v6)            ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
```

I also use cloudflare as my dns maybe that can help.
Here are my cloudflare ssl/tls settings :
[cloudflare-settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ndpGi.png)

So as I mentionned, I tried to add an ssl certificate on my domain, using [this tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-secure-nginx-with-let-s-encrypt-on-ubuntu-20-04)
And I just tried to do everything correctly, as I said, it worked for a little moment, then it stopped working.

I was expecting to have an ssl certificate, and this is what I got :
[google-error-message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r1vyw.png)

Comment: Questions about managing your server's configuration are better asked on [sf].